# vba need to create new workbook at a specific location with a specific name but my code is showing errors

Tags: vba

I am trying to add a excel workbook in a specific workbook with a specific name through vba but my code is showing errors
Here is my code

```
Private Sub CREATE_WORKBOOK()
activepath = ThisWorkbook.Path
MkDir activepath & "\Reports"
Dim seldir As String
seldir = Dir(activepath & "\Reports\Srikakulam.xlsx")
If seldir = "" Then
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename = activepath & "\Reports\Srikakulam.xlsx"
Else
End If
Set booktoopen = Workbooks.Open(activepath & "\Reports\Srikakulam.xlsx")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(C_Code.Text).Copy Before:=booktoopen.Sheets("Sheet1")
booktoopen.Close savechanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What specific errors and on which line?

Comment: "error 1004 : file could not be found"
Further workbook with name "False.xlsx" is being created in Documents folder

Comment: Has `ThisWorkbook` been saved already when this is run?  If not then `ThisWorkbook.Path` would be empty.

Comment: Yes. it is saved. I am trying to copy data in current workbook to a new workbook in reports folder in same path

Comment: @chandrasekharandassociates check below solution, it works and explanation why was it failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was not working is because few errors. The code that is trying to save the file here the syntax was incorrect

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename = activepath & "\Reports\Srikakulam.xlsx"
```

Here the correct syntax is

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs  Filename:= activepath & "\Reports\Srikakulam.xlsx"
```

In your case "**Filename = activepath**" would evaluate as boolen expression and result would false and the file would be created with FALSE as name. And later when the below codes gets executed it would result is *file not found exception* as the code would look for file "\Reports\Srikakulam.xlsx".
There were other issues, such as the check was wrong, check for directory if exists was not there etc.

```
Private Sub CREATE_WORKBOOK()
    Dim directoryName As String
    Dim isDirectoryExists As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim isFileExists As String
    
    activepath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    
    directoryName = activepath & "\Reports\"
    
    isDirectoryExists = Dir(directoryName, vbDirectory)
    
    If isDirectoryExists = "" Then
        MkDir directoryName
    End If
    
    fileName = directoryName & "Srikakulam.xlsx"
    
    isFileExists = Dir(fileName)
    
    If isFileExists = "" Then
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName
    End If
    
    Set booktoopen = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'Below line I have commented as C_Code.Text is not there
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(C_Code.Text).Copy Before:=booktoopen.Sheets("Sheet1")
    booktoopen.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```